# Template error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, web, rubygems

my Rails app works fine locally. But once I put it on a server and in production mode, I get this error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass) on line #7 of app/views/admin/confirm.rhtml:
4: <br>Description:
5: <br><%= @description %>
6: <br>Features:
7: <% @features.each do |feature| %>
8:      <br><%= feature.humanize %>
9: <% end %>
10: <br>Role data:

   app/views/admin/confirm.rhtml:7
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `send'
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `render'
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/template.rb:73:in `render_template'
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:256:in `render'
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:367:in `_render_with_layout'
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:254:in `render'
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1174:in `render_for_file'
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:896:in `render_without_benchmark'
```

Anyone have any idea what it means?

EDIT: OK I found out @features is nil. But I don't know how it is. In my create action I have:

```
flash[:name] = params[:name]
flash[:description] = params[:description]
flash[:role_data] = params[:role_data]
flash[:user_data] = params[:user_data]
flash[:features] = params[:features]
flash[:theme] = params[:theme]
redirect_to :action => "confirm"
```

Then in my confirm action I have:

```
def confirm
    @title = "Create a new simulation"
    @features = flash[:features]
    @name = flash[:name]
    @description = flash[:description]
    @role_data = flash[:role_data]
    @user_data = flash[:user_data]
    @theme = flash[:theme]
    flash.keep
  end
```

Comment: UHG what's up with the flash stuff? Wha..

Comment: You should probably inspect the object before sending it to the view. And again, what's up with the flash stuff??? :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @features instance variable is nil for that instance.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use the session object to pass data between actions. Flash is for passing messages between actions, not data!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `flash.keep` in the create action since you're using `redirect_to` and not `render`.

From [ActionController::Flash::FlashHash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash/FlashHash.html)

> When you need to pass an object to the current action, you use now, and your object will vanish when the current action is done.
>
> Entries set via now are accessed the same way as standard entries: flash[‘my-key’].